# highlight only typed keywords from string in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I am using following function to highlight searched keywords from string. It's working fine but having little issue.

```
$text="This is simple test text";
$words="sim text";
echo highlight($text, $words);
```

Using following function it is highlighting both "simple" & "text" words where I want it should highlight "sim" & "text" words only. What type of changes I need to make to achieve this result. Please advise.

```
function highlight($text, $words) 
{
    if (!is_array($words)) 
    {
        $words = preg_split('#\\W+#', $words, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }
    $regex = '#\\b(\\w*(';
    $sep = '';
    foreach ($words as $word) 
    {
        $regex .= $sep . preg_quote($word, '#');
        $sep = '|';
    }
    $regex .= ')\\w*)\\b#i';
    return preg_replace($regex, '<span class="SuccessMessage">\\1</span>', $text);
}
```

Comment: What's the reason you're using `\\b`, `\\w` and `\\W` instead of just `\b`,`\w` and `\W`?

Comment: It's giving same result in both cases. Please advise.

Comment: @KRA, what output do you want exactly for the sample input?

Comment: Hello, I want to just highlight searched text as here in sample I just want "sim" & "text" words to be highlighted. Currently it is highlighting entire "simple" word instead of "sim". This is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture all the relevant texts into groups for this.

Complete code: (I've marked lines which I have changed.)

```
$text="This is simple test text";
$words="sim text";
echo highlight($text, $words);

function highlight($text, $words)
{
    if (!is_array($words))
    {
        $words = preg_split('#\\W+#', $words, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }
    # Added capture for text before the match.
    $regex = '#\\b(\\w*)(';
    $sep = '';
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        $regex .= $sep . preg_quote($word, '#');
        $sep = '|';
    }
    # Added capture for text after the match.
    $regex .= ')(\\w*)\\b#i';
    # Using \1 \2 \3 at relevant places.
    return preg_replace($regex, '\\1<span class="SuccessMessage">\\2</span>\\3', $text);
}
```

Output:

```
This is <span class="SuccessMessage">sim</span>ple test <span class="SuccessMessage">text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi dont use php to highlight search words its takes some times to find and replace each word.

Use jquery it will be easier then php.

Simple example:

```
function highlight(word, element) {
var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
var repl = '<span class="yourClass">' + word + '</span>';
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl); }

highlight('dolor');
```

I hope it will help full.