# Php find String in foreach

Tags: php, search, foreach, highlight

How can I find an highlight a string in a foreach?

This loops through all users of my database and I want to find all lets say $um.

```
$um = "Um";
foreach($users as $user){
     # find here the string um or something
     echo $user;
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: take a look at [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). try to figure out how to use it by yourself. if you need more help let us know ;)

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422370/highlight-only-typed-keywords-from-string-in-php).

Comment: Why not use the MySQL to do the check? `WHERE user LIKE '%um%'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Big-O for PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions)

Comment: Why would it better to use this in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   $um  = "this is string contains um";

  $keyword[] = "um"; // the word/parts you wanna highlight

  $result = $um;

  foreach($keyword as $key)   {


    $result = str_replace($key, "<strong>$key</strong>", $result);
  }               


echo $result;
```

Comment: Good one. This is the direct answer.

Comment: This worked the only thing is that it does not style single characters just the full word

Answer (score 5):

In reality, I would do this in the query.. ..but

```
$um = "Um";

foreach($users as $user){

    if(strpos($user,$um) !== false){

        echo $user;

    }
}
```

*`strpos()` returns a string position, so a return value of '0' would be a match at the beginning of the string.  So, check for 'not false'*  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: I recommend and to check the mb_strpos if the work involves different languages with special chars..

Comment: Why would it better to use this in the query?

Comment: Because it would necessitate the need for a loop, a test, and would only return the results that you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_match`

```
$um = "Um";
foreach($users as $user){
     if( preg_match( "@$um@", $user, $matches ) ) echo $user;
}
```